# Why SELECT 'A' WHERE @val IN (1, 2, 3, NULL) does not return a value when @val IS NULL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In fact none of the following return a value. Why?

```
DECLARE @val AS INTEGER
SET @val= NULL
SELECT 'A' WHERE @val  IN (1, 2, 3, NULL)
SELECT 'B' WHERE @val NOT IN (1, 2, 3, NULL)
SELECT 'C' WHERE @val IN (1, 2, 3)
SELECT 'D' WHERE @val NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is equal to unknown not even `NULL` itself

Comment: Chuck noriss compared null to null and got true... or was it Jon Skeet?. :-)

Comment: Null can not be compared using a Operator, for this you would have to use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL. however if you still want to use an operate then you may try something like this ISNULL(@val,-1) IN (1, 2, 3, -1), where you replace a null with some dummy unused value and check for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparisons to NULL always return false unless you're using Is Null or Is Not Null.  You should change it to something like this:

```
SELECT 'A' WHERE @val IN (1, 2, 3) OR @val Is Null
```

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that in room are 5 women. You know 3 of them: Lisa, Sandra and another Lisa, 2 of them are strangers, so you don't know their names.

If someone asks you if these strangers have equal names, you couldn't answer, that because you don't know, so in this case you have no rows returned:

```
DECLARE @val AS NVARCHAR(20)
SET @val = NULL

DECLARE @Women AS TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Women VALUES (1,'Lisa'), (2,'Sandra'), (3,'Lisa'), (4,NULL), (5,NULL)

SELECT *
FROM @Women
WHERE @val IN (Name)
```

Also if someone asks you if strangers names aren't equal, you couldn't answer too, so no rows returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM @Women
WHERE @val NOT IN (Name)
```

So when you have NULL (unknown) you couldn't compare It.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of NULL always returns undefined value. Even this SQL will not return anything   select 1 where null = null
It suggest that NULL is just undefined.